# Terraform: data source aws_instance doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to work with aws_instance data source. I created a simple configuration which should create an ec2 instance and should return ip as output

```
variable "default_port" {
  type = string
  default = 8080
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
  shared_credentials_file = "/Users/kharandziuk/.aws/creds"
  profile                 = "prototyper"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0994c095691a46fb5"
  instance_type = "t2.small"

  tags = {
    name = "example"
  }
}

data "aws_instances" "test" {
  instance_tags = {
    name = "example"
  }
  instance_state_names = ["pending", "running", "shutting-down", "terminated", "stopping", "stopped"]
}

output "ip" {
  value = data.aws_instances.test.public_ips
}
```

but for some reasons I can't configure data source properly. The result is:

```
> terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.aws_instances.test: Refreshing state...

Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.

  on main.tf line 21, in data "aws_instances" "test":
  21: data "aws_instances" "test" {
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: Normally this is handled with resource exported attributes. You can update your `output` value to `aws_instance.example.public_ip` and remove your data to fix and optimize this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `depends_on` option into `data.aws_instances.test`.

like :

```sh
data "aws_instances" "test" {
  instance_tags = {
    name = "example"
  }
  instance_state_names = ["pending", "running", "shutting-down", "terminated", "stopping", "stopped"]

  depends_on = [
    "aws_instance.example"
  ]
}
```

It means that build `data.aws_instances.test` after make `resource.aws_instance.example`.

Sometimes, We need to use this option. Because of dependencies of aws resources.

> See :
>
> Here's [a document](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/dependencies.html) about `depends_on` option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a data source here. You can get the public IP address of the instance back from the resource itself, simplifying everything.

This should do the exact same thing:

```
resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-0994c095691a46fb5"
  instance_type = "t2.small"

  tags = {
    name = "example"
  }
}

output "ip" {
  value = aws_instance.example.public_ip
}
```